# Java JDBC hanging on DELETE statements

Tags: java, jdbc

I am running the below code:

```
protected String processDeleteQuery (String aTable) {

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = this.conn;
    String mResult = "Delete failed";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sqlstr = "delete from test_table where is_valid=2";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr);
        mResult = "Delete successful";
    } catch(SQLException sqlExcep) {
        sqlExcep.printStackTrace();
        mResult = "Delete failed - "+sqlExcep.getMessage();
    } finally {
        if(rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {} }
        if(stmt != null) { try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {} }
    }
    return mResult;
}
```

However the code is hanging at this line:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr);
```

and never returns from it, running endlessly.  The SQL statement "delete from test_table where is_valid=2" works quickly when I run it manually from SQL developer, and the INSERT and SELECT statements work for both for both the JDBC code and manually from SQL developer, just DELETE statements hang when run as JDBC code.  I have also tried PreparedStatements, but get the same results as above (only DELETE statements when run from JDBC hang).

Is there some reason why the JDBC executeQuery statements would hang for DELETE statements (such as concurrency, lock, permissions, etc reasons)?

I'm using Oracle DB version 11.2, JDK 1.8.0_101, and Tomcat v8.0,
with the driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

and running the server from Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Edit 1:

I've updated the code in the original post (removed the autocommit line, also tried it with setting it to "true", and changed executeQuery() to executeUpdate(), however, it is still hanging at the executeUpdate() line (meaning execution endlessly tries to process that line, but never returns from it)

Edit 2:

From JStack, there are a number of blocked threads (even though I made sure only one instance is running by closing all other windows, etc):

Thread 34051: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2039 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take() @bci=36, line=103 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take() @bci=1, line=31 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=149, line=1067 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() @bci=4, line=61 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 22275: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run() @bci=46, line=1344 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19715: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run() @bci=51, line=117 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 16643: (state = BLOCKED)

Thread 12547: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59, line=143 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=164 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36, line=209 (Interpreted frame)

Comment: What does `hang` mean here ? can you post stacktraces while it is in `hang` state

Comment: do not silently swallow exceptions - print them out.  Also change `executeQuery` to `executeUpdate`

Comment: There are a number of threads blocked: sorry, adding in the original post as it is hard to edit in the comments

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Comment: You say in your post that the code is hanging at rs = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr); and rs is a ResultSet. This should not compile at all, so it's not what you are actually running...

Comment: Sorry, edited again, was running just <code>stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr);</code>

Comment: This is not duplicate because the suggested answers (don't turn off autocommit, use executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery) does not work.  Plus the symptoms are different, the code hangs at when running the line <code>stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr); </code> and never returns from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're setting `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` which means that you need to commit the transaction at some point.

Try setting `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` and see what difference that makes.

From the oracle docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

> When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed. (To be more
>   precise, the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is
>   completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all
>   of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost
>   all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed,
>   right after it is executed.)

Also, use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code in the original post (removed the autocommit line, also tried it with setting it to "true", and changed executeQuery() to executeUpdate(), however, it is still hanging at the executeUpdate() line (meaning execution endlessly tries to process that line, but never returns from it).

Comment: You say in your post that the code is hanging at `rs = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr);` and `rs` is a `ResultSet`.  This should not compile at all, so it's not what you are actually running...

Comment: Sorry, edited again, was running just <code>stmt.executeUpdate(sqlstr);</code>

Comment: Turns out it was due to some uncommitted changes to the table from SQL developer, after closing SQL developer and rolling back all changes to the table, DELETE (through executeUpdate() from JDBC) is now working and no longer hangs.